# Xcode 8 Codegen feature generates nothing

Tags: ios, xcode8, codegen

I am trying to setup codegen feature in one of my existing project and I have no success with any code generation. Here goes my setup.

I have a Foo entity with a bar attribute. Codegen setup for Class Definition:

[image]

Language for Code Generation setup for Swift and Tools Version to automatic (Xcode 8).

[image]

Unfortunately when hitting build it outputs just Logs folder on DerivedData/CodeDataCodeGen* path.

[image]

I am mixing objc and swift in that project. Deployment target is setup for iOS 10. And yes, I've tried to clean project, delete derived data and save manually thousand of time. Any idea where the devil is or how to debug it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was generated actually. I've just searched on a wrong path. Correct folder was

> DerivedData/ProjectName-*/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TargetName.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/..